# Find two linear polynomials $f_0$ and $f_1$ such that $f_i(a_j) = 0$ and $f_i(a_i) = 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, real-numbers

I'm becoming crazy trying to figure out this problem that (I'm sure) is pretty simple. Literally, this is the formulate:

> Let $a_0, a_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a_0\not= a_1$. Build the linear polynomials $f_0$ and $f_1$ such that $f_i(a_j) = 0$ and $f_i(a_i) = 1$, for $i\not=j$ and $i,j\in\{0,1\}$.

At first I thought of $a_1$ and $a_0$ as the coefficients of those polynomials, but with only two coefficients you can't satisfy the initial conditions:

1. If $f_0(x) = f_1(x)$, then they are the same polynomial.
2. If $f_0(x) = a_0 + a_1x \land  f_1(x) = a_1+a_0x \land f_i(a_j) = 0 \land f_i(a_i) = 1$, then $a_0 = a_1 \Rightarrow\Leftarrow$

Therefore I assume that $a_0,a_1$ are not coefficients but some variables in $\mathbb{R}$, which leads me more or less nowhere. **What am I getting wrong?** It might help you (certainly not me) to know that the exercise title is *Lagrange interpolation*.

Comment: $a_i$ is root of polynomial $f_j$ whenever $i \ne j$. In general, the polynomials you seek are the [Lagrange polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial):
$f_\ell(x) = \prod\limits_{k=1,\ne \ell}^n \frac{x - a_k}{a_\ell - a_k}$

Comment: Your comment was very illustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about $f_0(x) = \frac{x-a_1}{a_0-a_1}$;  $f_1(x) = \frac{(x-a_0)}{(a_1-a_0)}$.

All I did was construct a linear polynomial $f_0$ s.t. $f_0(a_0)=1$ and $f_0(a_1)=0$, and then construct a linear polynomial $f_1$ s.t. $f_1(a_0)=0$ and $f_1(a_1)=1$.

Comment: Given that we have never talked about Lagrange interpolation in my classes, it was rather hard find that, since when I looked for a linear polynomial I never thought about something like $\frac{x-a_1}{a_0-a_1}$ as a linear polynomial. Thank you.